# How to add a separate header image for different pages using css

Tags: wordpress, image, header

I am working with a website and I need to put different images for headers of each page. And I think it's better to do with `css` so that it will be easy to edit in future

I have tried putting background image using `css`, problem is it is background image. It continues on what ever content I add.

```
body.page-id-656
{
   background-image:url('http://www.csichurchbangalore.com/wp- 
   content/uploads/2019/08/Untitled-1.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-size:100% 75%;
}
```

### Expected Result

Expected Result is a header image with a small height

### Actual Result

Back ground Image. It takes full height as the page.

Comment: post your header code

Comment: You setting background image on BODY, set it to header, and I suggest set height on header, then set `background-size: cover; background-position: center center;`

Comment: @Beneris , I tried putting header instead body as you said. But it doesn't made any change I wanted. If header is given instead body, a blank page only shows.

Comment: @Vel, I don't have a header code so far

Comment: You setting background image on BODY, set it to header,

Comment: @Vel. I did like you said. But when I give `header.page-id-656` its not even affecting my page. blank page is shown

Comment: can you share the site url?

Comment: I cannot see your style in header https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN1HH.png